# In emacs under cygwin keyboard mappings don't work

Tags: emacs, xemacs

When I run Gnu Emacs under cygwin on Windows and I press "ctrl-x ctrl-c" to exit I get the message:

ctrl-x ctrl-g is undefined

: However, when I run Xemacs the "ctrl-x ctrl-c" works fine

Comment: How are you running GNU Emacs?  In a xterm window?  In a DOS box?  Using X-Windows?  Are you running Xemacs the same way?

Comment: And for XEmacs I type "XEmacs" at the cygwin prompt

Comment: "From Cygwin" could mean a dozen different things.  What *exactly* are you typing "emacs" into?  Does emacs pop up its own window, or does it appear in whatever you typed "emacs" into?  How about XEmacs?

Comment: Sorry, I mean from a Cygwin command prompt. If I type XEmacs then it pops up into its own window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to put `set CYGWIN=tty` in your cygwin.bat.  See
http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html.  Or you could try running emacs under rxvt.  Or you could do what I do, which is use ["native" win32 emacs](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-23.1-bin-i386.zip).

Comment: Thanks, this worked setting CYGWIN=tty. My .emacs files loads 10x slower in emacs than in XEmacs but it works! I tried the "native" Win32 emacs link but it says "Server not found"